# Where can I find replacement double action hinges for an old, heavy door?

Tags: doors

I live in a Victorian-era house in Philadelphia. We have a double hung door into the kitchen and one of the hinges has completely given way. I need to find replacements but I'm having some problems finding the right replacement. 
Here is a photo of the original hinge, and there are [more online](http://www.flickr.com/photos/brianly/sets/72157629605344607/):

[image: Photo of the hinge]

It appears that [newer hinges](http://www.hardwaresource.com/images/products/Double_Acting_Diagram.jpg) have a slightly different design. Notice how the original folds compared to the one I linked to.

[image: Photo of closed hinge]

The door I'm hanging is about 1 1/4" thick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Van Dyke's Restorers](http://www.vandykes.com/) has lots of options, a little pricey but sometimes it is the only source